# Pandas weighted average on rows that contain a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, row

I have a dataframe indexed by date like follows:

```
date       id1 id2  id3   identifier  x_times  value
2016-01-01 123 1234 12345 a           21       56
2016-01-01 123 1234 12345 b           2        78
2016-01-01 123 1234 12345 c           10       23
```

I need to carry out a weighted average calculation where the identifier is only a and b for each date. The calculation should be:

((56 * 21) + (78 * 2)) / (21 + 2) = 57.91

Output:

```
date       id1 id2  id3   identifier  x_times  value  weighted_avg
2016-01-01 123 1234 12345 a           21       56     57.91
2016-01-01 123 1234 12345 b           2        78     57.91
2016-01-01 123 1234 12345 c           10       23
```

I have experimented with group bys and sums but I am struggling to rejoin the dataframe together with the weighted average.

What would be the easiest way of carrying out this calculation? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method to subset your original dataframe to smaller one. Then you could do your calculations with that subset dataframe and then using [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) you could assign it to the original dataframe:

```
subs = df.identifier.isin(['a','b'])
df_subs = df[subs]
df.loc[subs, 'weighted_avg'] = (df_subs.x_times * df_subs.value).sum() / df_subs.x_times.sum()

In [670]: df
Out[670]: 
            id1   id2    id3 identifier  x_times  value  weighted_avg
date                                                                 
2016-01-01  123  1234  12345          a       21     56     57.913043
2016-01-01  123  1234  12345          b        2     78     57.913043
2016-01-01  123  1234  12345          c       10     23           NaN
```

Comment: You could use `dropna` method to drop all rows which contain `NaN` in any of the columns. Or you could use `fillna` to fill `NaN` value to what you want. You could also check `NaNs` with `notnull()` and `isnull` methods.